# Why does SDF plugin syntax not support additional parameters like URDF?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All the gazebo ros plugins have a bunch of parameters that are set in the URDF and parsed by parser_urdf. SDFs don't seem to have the same functionality. As far as I can tell, the code doesn't even support it.

How would you supply parameters to the plugins inside an SDF?

Thanks!!
Piyush

EDIT #1:

It looks like I was reading the code incorrectly, and @AndreiHaidu's answer is correct. My test case uses VisualPlugins which still fails (all parameters get wiped in the SDF received by the visual plugin). Are VisualPlugin's supposed to have this same functionality as well?

Edit #2:

Here are a few files that should reproduce the error:

http://farnsworth.csres.utexas.edu/share/model.sdf
http://farnsworth.csres.utexas.edu/share/gazebo_ros_video.h
http://farnsworth.csres.utexas.edu/share/gazebo_ros_video.cc

The plugin works for the default parameters, displaying a ROS image topic inside gazebo.

Here's a bit more info that might be useful. I have a patch in the works that forwards visual plugins in parser_urdf. For my real setup I have verified that Gazebo receives the correct converted SDF:

```
<visual name='base_footprint_visuallaptop_screen_link'>
  <pose>0.236849 -0.000000 1.093250 0.000000 -1.047200 -0.000000</pose>
  <geometry>
    <box>
      <size>0.254000 0.330200 0.019050</size>
    </box>
  </geometry>
  <material>
    <script>
      <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
    </script>
  </material>
  <plugin name='laptop_video_controller' filename='libgazebo_ros_video.so'>
    <height>240</height>
    <width>320</width>
    <topicName>image_raw</topicName>
  </plugin>
</visual>
```

By the time this reaches Visual::Load, it gets changed to:

```
<visual name='robot1::base_footprint::base_footprint_visuallaptop_screen_link'>
  <geometry>
    <box>
      <size>0.254000 0.330200 0.019050</size>
    </box>
  </geometry>
  <pose>0.236849 0.000000 1.093250 0.000000 -1.047200 0.000000</pose>
  <material>
    <script>
      <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
      <uri>__default__</uri>
    </script>
  </material>
  <plugin name='laptop_video_controller' filename='libgazebo_ros_video.so'/>
</visual>
```

This is as far as I have gotten to figuring out whats going wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1986/why-does-sdf-plugin-syntax-not-support-additional-parameters-like-urdf?/) by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 138 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-20**:
Can you post your SDF. The visual plugin should behave exactly like every other plugin.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) on 2013-03-20**:
@nkoenig: see updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had a bit more time to take a look at this. It looks like unlike model Plugins, Visual Plugins are created by sending a visual message from Link::Load. At this time, the plugin msg does not support copying over the inner XML data from the SDF and this information is lost.

I've filed a bug report here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/598/visualplugin-parameters-lost-on-spawning-a

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) with karma: 138 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

This is possible, I will give you a template:

Here is a plugin example in the sdf file:

```
    <plugin name='plugin_name' filename='libplugin_name.so'>
    <sdf_parameter>69.0</sdf_parameter>
</plugin>
```

For example in the `Load` function of the plugin you can get the parameter as following:

```
void PluginName::Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
...
double param;

if (!_sdf->HasElement("sdf_parameter"))
{
    // if parameter tag does NOT exist
    std::cout << "Missing parameter <sdf_parameter> in PluginName, default to 0" << std::endl;
    param = 0;
}
    // if parameter tag exists, get its value
else param = _sdf->GetElement("sdf_parameter")->GetValueDouble();
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) on 2013-03-20**:
Thanks for the quick response. I'm using similar code which seems to be failing for VisualPlugins. I've updated the question.

**Comment by [Angelos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3366/angelos/) on 2017-06-28**:
Very helpful! Thanks